# Cannot Accept Google Android Market Terms and Conditions on Samsung Galaxy 7" tablet

Tags: samsung-galaxy-tab

I have a GT-P1000 Samsung Galaxy 7" Tablet wifi plus 3G. When I try to download a game, it goes straight to Android Market Terms of Service or Google Play Terms of service. However, when I scroll down the list, I cannot find an accept or decline box. So, I cannot proceed. I have tried clearing the cache in Market in Applications to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little bit strange, what you're writing, because I have exactly the same `Samsung Galaxy Tab GT-P1000` right here, with me, and I see absolutely no problems. I just did a factory reset of this device, to test your issue.

I taped on `Market` icon. Tabled asked me to provide my Google Account details, what I did. Right after that I saw license text and buttons to accept and decline, in the bottom of the screen. Note: *These buttons are not in the end of license text, instead they're always floating on the screen, so you can always see them, no matter, where in the license text you're*.

After clicking `Accept` my tablet automatically updated `Market` icon to `Google Play` icon and shown me on-screen information about this change.

I've been doing this (factory reset, license acceptance and `Market` to `Google Play` update) at least few times and have never encountered problems, like you described. If you still unable to see that `Accept` button or access `Market` / `Google Play` service, then I fear that factory reset of your device is the only option you're left with.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know a real solution for your problem, because I cannot remember when I had to accept that (too long ago). But I have some suggestions you could try:

- Try to wait, maybe there is some kind of interval before the button appears
- Try to use the menu option, maybe there is a menu option for accepting the ToS (I doubt it though)
- Contact Samsung support, maybe they've already encountered this problem before

Comment: Thanks for response. Have waited but nothing appears. Do you mean to contact samsung support. That is my next option I think.

Comment: Indeed, sorry for the typo :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try launching it and waiting a bit - eventually, it should turn into Google Play and you can accept the terms fine.